# D言語でのOpenSSLの使用

Tags: openssl, d

現在D言語でAES暗号を使おうと、OpenSSLをリンクしようとしています。
できれば既存の静的リンクライブラリを使用したいのですが可能でしょうか。
現状、dubでビルドしており、dub build とすると以下の様なエラーが出ます。

```
Linking...
OPTLINK (R) for Win32  Release 8.00.17
Copyright (C) Digital Mars 1989-2013  All rights reserved.
http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/optlink.html
C:\openssl\x86\lib\libeay32.lib
Error 43: Not a Valid Library File
```

OpenSSLのバージョンは以下のとおりです。
　OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

静的リンクライブラリ（アーカイブ）として　libeay32.lib / ssleay32.lib　を生成しています。
ビルドは、VisualStudio 2015で行いました。
これらライブラリが存在するディレクトリは以下のとおりです。

```
C:\openssl\x86\lib
```

Dコンパイラのバージョンは　DMD32 D Compiler v2.071.0  です。
ビルドはdubで行っています。

dub.jsonは以下のとおりです。

```
{
"name": "test",
"authors": [
    "test"
],
"sourceFiles":[
    "source\\app.def"
],
"description": "test",
"copyright": "test",
"license": "proprietary",
"dependencies":{
        "openssl": "~>1.1.4+1.0.1g"
},
"libs": [
        "curl","C:\\openssl\\x86\\lib\\libeay32","C:\\openssl\\x86\\lib\\ssleay32"
]
}
```

宜しくお願いします。

Comment: `libeay32.lib / ssleay32.lib` は COFF 形式でしょうから、`coffimplib` コマンドで OMF 形式に変換する必要があるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: http://www.prowiki.org/wiki4d/wiki.cgi?DigitalMarsTools　ここからDLしたもので「coffimplib libeay32.lib libeay32_d.lib」 を実行した所「Error: not an import library」とエラーを吐きました。。。たしかにこのファイルはdllをリンクするためのインポートライブラリではないのでそれはそうだという感じなのですが、なにかうまい方法はありますでしょうか。ちなみに、fileコマンドの結果は「libeay32.lib: current ar archive」と言う形です。